# Horizontal Constraint causes crash in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have two views. `subLabel` and `tinyImage`

I'd like the tinyImage to be right of subLabel, with a 10 pixel spacing.  This is what I have:

```
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: tinyImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        tinyImage.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
```

When I run this code, it crashes, and I see something like:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe89a6ece10 UILabel:0x7fe89a764cf0'2'.trailing == UIImageView:0x7fe89a765bb0.leading + 10>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

Comment: Are tinyImage and subLabel sibling views?

Comment: You should make sure that both `tinyImage` and `subLabel` have been added to the view hierarchy and you should add the constraint to the common superview rather than `tinyImage`, so probably `self.addConstraint` or `self.view.addConstraint` depending on what `self` is

Comment: @ReyGonzales Yes, infoView adds both views as subviews.

Comment: If they're both siblings, shouldn't you add the constraint to the superview? tinyImage.superview.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are adding the constraint in the view place. You can try add the constraint to the tinyImage's superview.

if you are supporting iOS8+ you could write:

```
horizontalConstraint.active = true
```

instead of

```
tinyImage.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
```

This will call addConstraint/removeConstraint automatically.

Comment: Do you  mean ```.active = true``` instead of ```activate```?